# Kendo toolbar append is not working

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, grid, telerik

I am trying to append my Kendo Grid toolbar after some functions using following::

1) I am getting the toolbar as::

```
    var toolbar = $("#Grid").find(".k-grid-toolbar").html();
```

2) then after some changes to Grid using `grid.setOptions(JSON.parse(options))` which causes disappear of Toolbar i am again appending toolbar to grid as::

```
    $("#Grid").find(".k-grid-toolbar").html(toolbar);
```

Here toolbar is appended properly but I am not able to use those functions(i.e. Dropdown inside of toolbar).

How can i get my toolbar Dropdown working?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show a JSFiddle/JSBin/SO snippet that reproduces the original problem? I.e. where `setOptions` makes your toolbar disappear?

Comment: @OnaBai http://dojo.telerik.com/@rjha999/IlOHO here is the snippet. In which toolbar stop its functionality whenever we are appending it

Comment: There are two problem: 1st without saving and restoring the toolbar,  `JSON.stringify` does not perform a deep copy so you are actually not saving the `DropDownList` definition and that's why when you do a `setOptions` you see the `DropDownList` as an `input`; 2nd saving the HTML using `html()`, you only copy the DOM code but not the data and events associated with it, when you reapply it you only have the visual effect. Do you need to save all the options or would be enough saving only sorting, columns definition and a few more?

Comment: @OnaBai I need to save all options with Dropdown's selected value as well.
But how can i do this?

Comment: Reinitializing the DropDownList http://dojo.telerik.com/@OnaBai/opilo but you need to save the DropDownList value as well otherwise after reinitializing it, you have the filter but not the correct value in the DropDownList

Comment: @OnaBai Thanks that worked. But loosing all the functionalities Like tootip on any Label/button or other events like this is not working.
Maybe something will get release in next update of kendo.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the `html()` method provides ONLY the HTML code, and not the JavaScript attached to the elements from this HTML. So when you inject your HTML code in the toolbar, you need to call again the JavaScript attached to the elements. If you want to get a kendo widget configuration, for example a dropdownList, you need to call `options` and `dataSource` from your widget.

E.g:

```
var $toolbar = $("#Grid").find(".k-grid-toolbar"),
    toolbar = $toolbar.html(),
    // Dropdown list Element
    $ele = $("input[name=myInput]", $toolbar.get(0)),
    // Dropdown list Widget object
    ddl = $ele.data("kendoDropDownList"),
    cfg = ddl.options;
// toJSON returns objects without the observer properties
cfg.dataSource = ddl.dataSource.data().toJSON();

// HERE YOU REBUILD YOUR TABLE

$toolbar.html(toolbar);
$("input[name=myInput]", $toolbar.get(0)).kendoDropDownList(cfg);
```

If the elements you add to the toolbar are always the same, I would suggest you create instead a function with the grid as argument (and the data, if the data changes):

```
function setToolbarContent(grid){
  var $toolbar = grid.find(".k-grid-toolbar");
  $toolbar.html('My HTML String');
  $toolbar.find("input[name=myInput]").kendoDropDownList({my: 'cfg'});
}
```

And by the way, if you were adding the toolbar config and template to grid.setOptions(), maybe it wouldn't disappear in the first place :)